# pulling subset of lines from files

Tags: python, string

I have files where there is a varying number of header lines in random order followed by the data that I need, which spans the number of lines as given by the corresponding header. ex `Lines: 3`

```
from: blah@blah.com
Subject: foobarhah
Lines: 3
Extra: More random stuff

Foo Bar Lines of Data, which take up
some arbitrary long amount  characters on a single line, but no  matter how long 
they still only take up the number of lines as specified in the header
```

How can I get at that data in one read of the file?? 
P.S. The data is from the 20Newsgroups corpus.

Edit: The quick solution I guess which only works if I relax the constraint on reading only once is this:

- [1st read] Find out `total_num_of_lines` and match on first `Lines:` header ,
- [2nd read] I discard the first `(total_num_of_lines- header_num_of_lines)` and then read the rest of the file

I'm still unaware of a way to read in the data in one pass though.

Comment: So you just want the `Foo Bar Lines...` at the end? What format is this file in - is this all just plain text? And is there anything after the text at the end?

Comment: +1 to the comment above; important questions are: 1) does the file end with those data; 2) can the file be large?

Comment: Its just plain text, it ends with the last line of the data I need, aka no trailing empty lines, and the length isn't  any longer than 200 or so lines, average being close to 100

Comment: If the file ends with the last line of data you need, and that data is always preceded by a blank line as in your sample, then you can just skip the header until you hit a blank line and ignore the Lines: header completely

Comment: @mattclemens : Only 200 lines tops ? Why wouldn't you use `.readlines()`, then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we have the general case where there could be multiple messages following each other, maybe something like

```
from itertools import takewhile
def msgreader(file):
    while True:
        header = list(takewhile(lambda x: x.strip(), file))
        if not header: break
        header_dict = {k: v.strip() for k,v in (line.split(":", 1) for line in header)}
        line_count = int(header_dict['Lines'])
        message = [next(file) for i in xrange(line_count)] # or islice..
        yield message
```

would work, where

```
with open("53903") as fp:
    for message in msgreader(fp):
        print message
```

would give all the listed messages.  For this particular use case the above would be overkill, but frankly it's not much harder to extract all the header info than it is only the one line.  I'd be surprised if there weren't already a module to parse these messages, though.

Comment: I quickly looked into other python libs that dealt with corpus data, couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure you even need the beginning of the file in order to get its contents. Consider using split:

```
_, contents = file_contents.split(os.linesep + os.linesep) # e.g. \n\n
```

If, however, the lines parameter does count - you can use the technique suggested above along with parsing file headers:

```
headers, contents = file_contents.split(os.linesep + os.linesep)

# Get lines length
headers_list = [line.split for line in headers.splitlines()]
lines_count = int([line[1] for line in headers_list if line[0].lower() == 'lines:'][0])

# Get contents
real_contents = contents[:lines_count]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the state of whether the headers have finished. That's all.